# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'auth' of 'urlObj' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have tried multiple way to resolve this but only way I found is not to include the header section.

Here is the code for header section which when included in the page gives this error on deployment & no error on local build or in development. I tried using explicit href to counter this as written on some forums but without any result.

Anyone have any idea?

enter image description here

```js
const Header = ({
    siteName = "Semantic Pen",
    headersMenuItems = [{ name: 'Try it', link: '#appDemo' }, { name: 'How it Works', link: '#How-it-works' },
    { name: 'Use Cases', link: '#use-cases' }],
    CTAButton = 'Try Now',
    logoLocation = 'vercel.svg'
}) => {
    const logoAlt = `Logo for ${siteName}`;
    const [isMenuOpen, setIsMenuOpen] = useState(false);

    const toggleMenu = () => {
        setIsMenuOpen(!isMenuOpen);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const closeMenuOnResize = () => {
            if (window.innerWidth > 1023) {
                setIsMenuOpen(false);
            }
        };

        window.addEventListener('resize', closeMenuOnResize);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', closeMenuOnResize);
        };
    }, [isMenuOpen]);


    if (!siteName || !headersMenuItems || !CTAButton || !logoLocation) {
        // You can return a loading state or an error message.
        return <div className="flex flex-row text-xl mt-4">Some headers data not Availale...
            <Skeleton className="w-[500px] h-[40px] rounded-full" />
        </div>;
    }


    return (
        <>
            <header className="p-4 flex flex-row mt-2">
                {/* Left side - Logo */}
                <div className="flex" id="logoSection">
                    <Image
                        src={logoLocation}
                        width={50}
                        height={50}
                        alt={logoAlt}
                    />
                    <div className="ml-2 mt-1 text-2xl font-bold">
                        <Link href={process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SITE_HOMEPAGE_URL}>{siteName}</Link>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <NavigationMenu className={`hidden lg:flex flex-grow ml-auto`}> */}
                    <NavigationMenuList className={`pl-20 pr-12 lg:flex-row justify-between`}>
                        {headersMenuItems.map((menuItem, index) => (
                            <NavigationMenuItem key={menuItem?.link}>
                                <Link href={menuItem?.link || ''} legacyBehavior passHref className='px-4'>
                                    <NavigationMenuLink className={navigationMenuTriggerStyle()}>
                                        {menuItem?.name}
                                    </NavigationMenuLink>
                                </Link>
                            </NavigationMenuItem>
                        ))}

                    </NavigationMenuList>

                </NavigationMenu>
            </header>
            <Separator />
        </>

    );
};

export default Header;
```

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Probably `process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SITE_HOMEPAGE_URL` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks not sure why it was not able to read